# STM32f107xx LCD Screen

Tags: stm32, lcd

I have an STM3210C-Eval Board on which I'm trying to display text on the LCD Screen. The problem is that the text displayed on the Screen is upside down ( you need a mirror to read it correctly).

Comment: Your question is as vague as it gets. Do you really think anyone could even hope to help you, given what little information you provided?

Comment: Sorry, but the problem is obviously in the stm32 source file containing the functions that display text on the screen,i thought maby someone had the same problem and fixed it